# Intercept files deleting in Android OS

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I need to know when a file is deleted from an android device, is it possibile? Are there some intents about the request to delete a file from device or SD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a file observer for files in some locations (though I've heard rumors this may not work for the simulated "external storage" on some recent versions).

But there is no way to "intercept" as in prevent such deletion, short of modifying the installation of android.

If the file is readable to your app, you could presumably make a backup copy ahead of time.

Comment: My idea was to develope a sort of recycle bin where to copy deleted files. But I think it is not possible...